# How to write test for HOC in jest & enzyme

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme, react-router-v4

Our app currently uses react router and HOCs to create authentication in or system. I've been comfortable with writing tests for components that don't have an extra layer of authentication but am stumped on how to tackle this code I wrote. I've been looking for documentation specifically about react-router authentication and am stuck. What would be the best approach to handle HOC's that are within react router?

index.js

```
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(reduxThunk)(createStore);
const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers);
const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
if (token) {
  store.dispatch({ type: AUTH_USER });
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App id={token} />
  </Provider>,
  document.querySelector('.app')
);
```

App.js

```
function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, auth, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        auth ? (<div><Component {...props} /></div>) : (
          <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}

function PublicRoute({ component: Component, auth, ...rest }) {
  return <Route {...rest} render={props => (!auth ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/dashboard" />)} />;
}

class App extends Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object,
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={history} >
        <Switch>
          <PublicRoute auth={this.props.auth} path="/login" exact component={Login} />
          <PrivateRoute auth={this.props.auth} path="/dashboard" exact component={Dashboard} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    auth: state.auth.authenticated,
  };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  null
)(App);
```